# Unit Testing Spring Services with actual Repository with in memory database

Tags: junit4, spring-boot-test

I am trying to test my `@Service` with the actual object of Spring Data Repository, where I am trying to use in memory database.I am using below annotation in my unit test.

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@EnableJpaRepositories
@SpringBootTest(classes = {MyService.class})
public class T24PortfolioRequestHandlerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository myRepository;

    @Test
    public void handleRequest() {        
        String output = myService.handleRequest(testData, "123", "TEST");
        Assert.assertNotNull(output);
        Assert.assertEquals("TESTING", output);

    }
}
```

I am getting below exception while running the test.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.....respository.MyRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

If I specify `MyRepository.class` in `SpringBootConfiguratio(classes={MyService.class, MyRepository.class})` I am getting below error.

```
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [...respository.MyRepository]: Specified class is an interface
```

Is there any another way to tell spring boot about my repositories?

Comment: But in the SpringBootTest annotation you told it to only include MyService.

Comment: `@SpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class})` if i put this it will load everything,I just want to load the services and component which are required for my tests. I can not specify `MyRepository.class` in `@SpringBootTest` annotation as it does not accept interface.

Comment: I hope spring is smart enough to find out all the dependency of my test class.

Comment: It is, but it finds them in the application context. You've explicitly told it that context only contains one class.

Comment: @SpringBootTest(classes = {MyService.class}) seems to be incorrect here we generally pass the class name annotated with @SpringBootApplication

Comment: Yes that will load the entire context and test will work fine, but loading full application context which i am trying to avoid

Comment: You need to pass the *implementation* of the `MyRepository` interface that you want to inject in the slimmed-down context.